# Which to use, concat, concat_ws? in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, I need to change this data

```
FirstName | MiddleName | LastName
---------------------------------
Robert    | Thomas     | Smith
```

Into the string "Smith, Robert Thomas"

I'm not sure if I need to use a `join`, `concat` or `concat_ws`.

I know that if I use

```
concat_ws(', ',LastName,FirstName,MiddleName)
```

Then I get "Smith, Robert, Thomas" but i need  "Smith, Robert Thomas".

Any advice?

Answer (score 35):

I realise this is a necro but it is worth noting the following:

Both [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) & [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) are largely equivalent.

However, the most noteworthy difference is that [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) might not return the results you are expecting for cases where any of the inputs are NULL. In these cases [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) will return NULL whereas [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) will skip NULL values and still return a string with the result of the remaining inputs. This means that in most cases you will probably want to use [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws).

The following are equivalent except where one or more inputs are NULL:

```
// Result: LastName, FirstName, MiddleName
CONCAT( LastName, ', ', FirstName, ', ', MiddleName )

// Result: LastName, FirstName, MiddleName
CONCAT_WS( ', ', LastName, FirstName, MiddleName )
```

In cases where you want to use [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) with different 'separators' just set the first input to an empty string:

```
// Result: LastName, FirstName (MiddleName)
CONCAT_WS( '', LastName, ', ', FirstName, ' (', MiddleName, ')' )
```

Answer (score 9):

Then just use

```
CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstnName, ' ', MiddleName)
```

CONCAT_WS is used to concatenate with only one seperator while the CONCAT appends strings together in any way you want.

Comment: Thank you, between work and homework i think my brain has left for the day!!.. such a simple answer don't know why i didn't think of it. lol..

Comment: @TommyCombs Remember to flag answers, they are the basis on what ranking work, flagging answers and contributing gives points and this is what motives people to continue coming back to S-O

Answer (score 0):

Write you SQL like this to get desired result:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', author_lname, CONCAT(author_fname,' ', author_lastname)) AS info FROM books;
```

It will return output:

Smith, James Blake